# Kafka (jackson) Serializer Deserializer StackOverflowError

Tags: jackson, apache-kafka, jackson-databind

```
public class MyCastMessage{
    public String Src;
    public String Dest;

    public Types Type;
    public Description description;
}

public class Description{
    public String title;
    public String Body;
    public ArrayList<ElementDescriptor> elements;
}

public class ElementDescriptor {
    public int tagValue;
    public boolean optional;
    public boolean extAddition;
    public Atype data;
}
```

I need to Serialize Deserialize  **MyCastMessage** Using Kafka Serializer Deserializer.
I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson` **ObjectMapper**

```
public class JsonPOJOSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    /**
     * Default constructor needed by Kafka
     */
    public JsonPOJOSerializer() {
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> props, boolean isKey) {
    }

    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        if (data == null)
            return null;

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error serializing JSON message", e);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
    }

}
```

the above is my JsonPOJOSerializer class

but I'm getting this error bellow

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:737)
```

Comment: Does the object graph you are trying to serialize have non-terminating cycles?

Comment: I skipped it, i just Serde as bytes for now so i can form a simplified model